# Chage url without redirect using httacess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have completed my project. Now client wants to change the url.

`abc.com/booking` **to** `abc.com/reserve`

I have used abc.com/booking in many pages. So I don't want to redirect.

Is there any way to change url text `booking` to `reserve` ?

I have used CI framework.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the project is just finished, I would recommend to simply change all `/booking` to `/reserve` on all pages. Otherwise you introduce a "hack", which feels strange to do on a new fresh site.

Comment: Does Ci framework not use some kind of router so you only need to define it in one place?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Surely `find & replace` are your best bet here? (possibly with a `301` in case you miss something)

Answer (score -1):

Put this line in .httacess

```
Redirect abc.com/booking  abc.com/reserve
```